# Rails and OpenURI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run the following snippet from a brand new rails project in the console:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_279ec8ee3427_64.png")
data = open(uri)
```

This errors with:

```
TypeError: can't convert URI::HTTP into String
    from (irb):24:in `open'
    from (irb):24
    from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm running on Rails 3.0.4 and Ruby 1.9.2. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You probably should add `.read` to your `open`, like so: `data = open('http://www.example.com/').read` otherwise you'll have an IO handle ready to read, but no content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

open-uri wants a string.

```
data = open("http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_279ec8ee3427_64.png")
```

Comment: If you only use `open` you haven't received any content, you've only created a file handle: `data.class #=> Tempfile`. You have to `read` the file handle to actually receive anything.

Answer (score 30):

`open()` will accept both a string and a URI object.

```
io = open("http://...")
io = open(URI.parse("http://..."))
```

The error you described will happen if `open-uri` is not included.

```
require 'open-uri'
```